# Keycloak: cannot get token from a custom spi

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have to create two rest services via keycloak.
The first one sends a verification code to a phone number. The second one grant a token to a user if the verification code is correct for a given phone number.

I have created a module with a custom SPI following the guide in https://github.com/FX-HAO/keycloak-phone-authenticator. The provider can be found. I have also created the Direct grant flow copy and made it the default direct grant flow for the realm.

I can send the verification code with a request to http://{host}//auth/realms/{my_realm}/{my_provider}/send_sms

However, I cannot get the token using the following request:

```
curl -X POST  http://{host}/auth/realms/{my realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token  
-H 'authorization: Basic {my keycloak admin username and password}'  
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -d 'grant_type=password&phone_number={phone number}&code={code}'
```

I keep getting the invalid_client_credentials error and it seems that my provider is not called because there is nothing in its logs.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are simply missing the `client_id` and `client_secret` in your request.

Comment: what is the meaning of client_id and client_secret in this case? Are they the "technical user" identifiers or are they the phone number and the verification code?

Comment: It's neither phone number nor verification code. Just the OIDC standard id for your client and it's secret.

Comment: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/

Comment: thank you, I used the login user data. Now I've created a new client and added the direct grant option to it, but now I get
```{
   "error": "invalid_grant",
   "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
}
```
The client_secret and the client_id are correct as well as the phone number and the verification code. The default direct grant flow is set as my custom flow.

Comment: Sorry, it was due to wrong user id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sventorben said, the problem was in specifying wrong credentials for the client